# Sphinx(Search) - documents which matches keyword twice (thrice, etc.)

Tags: sphinx, sphinxql

Is there a way to only output documents which contains `n` matches of a search term in it?

F.e. I want to output all documents containing the search term `"Pablo Picasso" | "Picasso Pablo"` at least two (three, n) times. 
How would such a query look like?

My current query is:
`SELECT * FROM myIndex WHERE MATCH('"Pablo Picasso" | "Picasso Pablo"');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it with filtering by weight (ie results with it multiple time wil rank higher)

But a useful trick is the Strict order operator...

```
MATCH('Pablo << Pablo')
```

would require the word twice (ie one before the other!)

---

You can also use the primoxity operator to simplify your original query, it just wants the words near each other, which is more conise than two phrase operators

```
MATCH('"Pablo Picasso"~1')
```

... ie within 1 word of each other - ie adjent.

---

Combine the two..

```
MATCH('"Pablo Picasso"~1 << "Pablo Picasso"~1')
```

and for theree occurances

```
MATCH('"Pablo Picasso"~1 << "Pablo Picasso"~1 << "Pablo Picasso"~1')
```